# Connecting two EC2 Windows instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, octopus-deploy

I need to connect two Windows EC2 instances. One instance will serve as an Octopus Deploy Server, the other as a Deployment target with a tentacle.
The two instances are running in the default VPC with the same security group.
For now I allowed all TCP traffic through the security group.
Octopus Server needs port 10933 opened to communicate with it's tentacles. I created a firewall rule to allow outgoing traffic through port 10933 on the Octopus Server instance and an Incoming Firewall rule to allow traffic through port 10933 on the Tentacle instance.

The two instances can ping each other, but the Octopus Server is unable to find the tentacle on the other EC2 instance.

What am I missing?

Comment: What happens if you allow all traffic on your firewall ?

Comment: I disabled the firewall on both EC2 instances. But I get the following error when Octopus tries to connect: `Pipefish.Errors.PipefishCommunicationException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond [Ipaddress]:10933`

Comment: Something is fishy with your security groups and firewall configs. Are you sure you are allowing everything on your security groups ?

Comment: This is what I have as the security group setting: `Type             Protocol   Port Range  Source RDP              TCP        3389        0.0.0.0/0 All TCP          TCP        0 - 65535   0.0.0.0/0 MS SQL           TCP        1433        0.0.0.0/0 HTTP             TCP        80          0.0.0.0/0 Custom TCP Rule  TCP        10993       0.0.0.0/0 All ICMP         All        N/A         0.0.0.0/0`
 And as I said for this experiment I turned the firewalls completely off.

Comment: I find that for most of the time, networking between two EC2 instances is absolutely fine, but occasionally, I get the exact same problem, they just don't want to talk to each other...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, had to allow in AWS Console under Security Groups a custom TCP rule allow a incoming connection on the octopus tentacle port (10933).

After settings this, and enabling it on the server firewall it worked.